# Transfer Ether through a smart contract

Tags: web3js, transactions

I'm pretty new to web3.
I'm writing a simple smart contract to receive ETH and transfer it to a fix address, really a simple smart contract.

Its work well with standard token but not with Ether.
Can you help me with this?. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to let smart contract receive ether, you need to add a **payable function** to the SC. Something like this will work for a function

```
function deposit() external payable {
//function logic here
}
```

Also, if you want the whole smart contract becomes a payable one. You can just simply add the following line in the SC

```
receive() external payable {}
```

Comment: Wowww, it works like champ. I do not know it is that simple. I wonder if the smart contract to receive ether just like a regular user account by adding that code line?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It will make the SC act like a regular address.